# Numeric value: day of the week

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Im changing text value based on the day of the week, I was able to achieve this using string values, however I want to be able to achieve on a numeric value instead - to remove issues with different languages. For example, if today is monday do... but I want if today is day 1 then do. Ive tried the code below but it gives me a numeric value of 0;

```
    NSDateFormatter *dayofweekformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dayofweekformatter setDateFormat:@"E"];

NSString *DayOfWeek = [dayofweekformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger weekDay = [DayOfWeek integerValue];
NSLog(@"The day of the week is: %d", weekDay);
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/) link, "E" on its own will give you the day of the week as a textual format, i.e.: "Mon"/"Tue" etc.

If you want the day of the week as an integer, you should use a lower case "e" or "c".

A different implementation would be to use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` to determine the day of the week as this is more likely to take into consideration different settings across different devices based on the users preferred calendar.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:date];

NSLog(@"day of the week: %i", [dateComponents weekday]);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, worked like a charm. Could you elaborate on "A different implementation..."

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution proposed on Apple forums https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1700102?start=0&tstart=0 (I am not the author)

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents =[gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:dateOfInterest];

NSInteger weekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
// weekday 1 = Sunday for Gregorian calendar

[gregorian release];
```

Comment: Thanks, what is `dateOfInterest` ?